# WKWebView - Margin Top

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm starting swift.

Code is a webview without superior navigation, constrain moves the webview from the top leaving an upper margin.

see the image

[Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNZO2.png)

My code

```
import UIKit 
import WebKit 

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webView
}()

func setupUI() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor)
    ])
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
    
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com.br/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!,cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    
}

}
```

Comment: try to remove safe area constraint from top of webView, change it to self.view.topAnchor

Comment: I tried the modification.

NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
             webView.topAnchor.constraint (equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
             webView.leftAnchor.constraint (equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
             webView.bottomAnchor.constraint (equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
             webView.rightAnchor.constraint (equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor)
         ])

the margin is visible.

Comment: You can add your own answer then mark the question as `solved`, that way others will see there is an answer to this question and know there is a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just add:

```
self.navigationController? .isNavigationBarHidden = true
```